Is there a GitHub action to fetch Sentry Issues and create GitHub Issues?
I would like to automate creating GitHub Issues based on Sentry Issues (which are automatically generated from detected server errors for our applications.)
I am hosting Sentry on a public-facing server.  However, my Github server is only accessible from my company's internal network.  For this reason, we can't use the normal Sentry-GitHub integrations because our sentry Server can't reach our Github server.
However, since our GitHub server can reach our Sentry server, I'd like a GH Action which could check Sentry for new issues, and replicate them in Github to be assigned to our dev team.   Does anyone know of such a GH action?
